# Magento 1.8.1.0 - Applying patch 10266 failed

Tags: magento-1.8, patches

I'am trying to apply patch 10266 to my magento 1.8.1.0 installation.

I've uploaded the patch to the root of the magento installation.

The strange thing is the patch is trying to patch this file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php` but the file is not present in a clean install of magento 1.8.1.0

When I run the patch it gives me the following output:

Executed command: `sh PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2017-09-13-06-28-08.sh`

```
PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2017-09-13-06-28-08.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2017-09-13-06-28-08.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2017-09-13-06-28-08.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2017-09-13-06-28-08.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2017-09-13-06-28-08.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2017-09-13-06-28-08.sh: cannot create 0: Permission denied
PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2017-09-13-06-28-08.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2017-09-13-06-28-08.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 49 with fuzz 2 (offset -27 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 73 (offset -27 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Grid/Renderer/Notice.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/QueueController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/TemplateController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 579 (offset -5 lines).
can't find file to patch at input line 280
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|index 8618bca..d3aba19 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 421 (offset -3 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/Serializer/Adapter/PhpCode.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/file.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/toolbar.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login-simple.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/history.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
checking file app/design/install/default/default/template/install/create_admin.phtml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
checking file downloader/template/login.phtml
```

Applied.patches.list:

```
2015-02-17 13:24:26 UTC | SUPEE-5344 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1 | a5c9abcb6a387aabd6b33ebcb79f6b7a97bbde77 | Thu Feb 5 19:14:49 2015 +0200 | v1.14.1.0..HEAD
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #2 succeeded at 537 (offset -4 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
patching file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php


2015-05-18 08:35:38 UTC | SUPEE-5998 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1 | 9324d922a64fac99ceb3725062eb498d634401dc | Thu May 14 13:46:45 2015 +0300 | v1.14.1.0..HEAD
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/messages.phtml
patching file get.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php


2016-10-24 13:58:39 UTC | SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.8.1.0 | v1 | b2fac29e26174150c655a15a6aae41634cb4420f | Tue Jun 23 08:57:53 2015 +0300 | 76d0bc3c0b..b2fac29e26
patching file app/Mage.php
patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
patching file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file downloader/lib/.htaccess
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml
patching file errors/processor.php


2016-10-24 14:08:49 UTC | SUPEE-6482 | CE_1.9.2.0 | v1 |  | Tue Jul 14 14:17:04 2015 +0300 |
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 209 (offset -24 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php


2016-10-24 14:32:05 UTC | SUPEE-6788 | CE_1.8.1.0 | v1 | 854766736b694382a6c5ad5d64327c32fb26f0b9 | Fri Oct 23 13:52:50 2015 +0300 | 4263b8c
patching file .htaccess
patching file .htaccess.sample
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Soap/Server.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Exception.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
patching file cron.php
patching file errors/processor.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php


-e 2017-09-29 08:38:03 UTC | SUPEE-2747 | EE_1.13.1.0 | v1 | 5b7ff40ed56add4988dbf03f661f844f47ab140f | Tue Jan 14 18:36:41 2014 +0200 | v1.13.1.0..HEAD
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
```

Update:

Applying Patch 7405 v1: `sh PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2016-01-20-04-47-00.sh`

Output:

```
PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2016-01-20-04-47-00.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2016-01-20-04-47-00.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2016-01-20-04-47-00.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2016-01-20-04-47-00.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2016-01-20-04-47-00.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2016-01-20-04-47-00.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #2 FAILED at 43.
Hunk #3 succeeded at 64 with fuzz 2 (offset -4 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Admin.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 65 (offset -3 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/options/type/file.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/creditmemo/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/renderer/default.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals/discount.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
checking file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
checking file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
```

Comment: you missed some of patch file. can you please all old patches are applied.
particular  SUPEE-7405 patch

Comment: @RamaChandranM Thank you for your answer, see updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php` check with Magento 1.8.1.0 core file any change or any space in that file.

other are files are applied correctly.

You are missing some of your patch  `SUPEE-8788, SUPEE-9652, SUPEE-9767` please check and apply.

Comment: not SUPEE-9667 its SUPEE-9767